# Interacting with a .db file from Linux shell

Tags: database, linux, shell, raspberry-pi

I recently installed minidlna, a lightweight UPnP server, on my Raspberry Pi. Since this lacks the web interface of other programs such as Mediatomb, I thought it could be an interesting project for me to write one.

I believe minidlna stores library information in a single file named "files.db".

---

EDIT: I was advised to check the output of `file files.db` - this was as follows:

`files.db: SQLite 3.x database, user version 8`

---

However, I can't find a program that lets me interact with .db files from the shell. I've seen the following programs recommended:

- isql
- dbaccess
- sql
- SQLite3
- db.util

In the first four cases, `sudo apt-get install` cannot find the programs.

`sudo apt-get install db.util` appears to install, but partway through installation, yields the following messages:

```
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up gcj-4.7-base (4.7.1-1) ...
Setting up libgcj-common (1:4.6.3-7) ...
Setting up libgcj13 (4.7.1-1) ...
Setting up libgcj13-awt (4.7.1-1) ...
Setting up gcj-4.7-jre-headless (4.7.1-1) ...
Illegal instruction
ERROR: gcj-dbtool did fail; known problem on armv6l
Setting up gcj-4.7-jre (4.7.1-1) ...
Setting up gcj-4.7-jre-lib (4.7.1-1) ...
Setting up gcj-jre-headless (4:4.7.1-1) ...
Setting up gcj-jre (4:4.7.1-1) ...
Setting up libservlet2.5-java (6.0.35-5) ...
Setting up libhsqldb-java (1.8.0.10-11) ...
Setting up hsqldb-utils (1.8.0.10-11) ...
```

Thereafter, `which db-util`, `which db.util`, and `which dbutil` do not yield any results.

Is db.util the correct program to be installing to interact with .db files? If so, how can I fix the reported error with gcj-dbtool? If not, could someone recommend a better program?

Comment: Did you try and see what `file` said about it?

Comment: I didn't, as I'd never heard of that program (I'm very new to Linux) - have added info in original question.

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have to install a package named 'sqlite' or 'sqlite3'.

Then you will be able to interact with your .db file using

```
$ sqlite3 files.db
> SELECT blah FROM your_table WHERE ......
```

In your post you mention 'SQLite3', the package name should have no caps letters.

Did you run an `apt-cache search sqlite` ?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that the package name shouldn't have capital letters - is that a general rule, or simply for this package?

sqlite3 is installing as I type this - I'll accept this as the answer if it works - otherwise, I'll be back here begging help!

Comment: I'd say that it is not an absolute rule, but Linux distributions generally avoid putting caps in package names. Of course 'generally' means there are exceptions. But I'm pretty sure that the exact package name for sqlite should have no caps on the distribution you are using (seems to be Debian based). Did you try 'apt-cache search sqlite' as suggested in my answer, to know the exact name of the package you have to install?

Comment: I must admit, I didn't try `apt-cache search sqlite` (again, hadn't heard of this usage before) - I simply trusted in your knowledge that sqlite3 was the correct package name.

I tried it just now, though, and it produced a veritable treasure trove of alternatives!

sqlite3 is installed and working perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use python, since it should already be on your Raspberry Pi and comes with batteries / [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) included.

```
python -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.connect('example.db').cursor().execute('SELECT * FROM stocks ORDER BY price').fetchall())"
```